# How to refresh Composer install to restore missing (deleted) files

Tags: 8, composer

I attempted to install the 8.8.1 Drupal Core security update using the command

```
composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies
```

I've used this many times. However, this time the update failed with the following messages

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 12 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating symfony/finder (v3.4.33 => v3.4.36): PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught 
Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Finder\Comparator\NumberComparator' not found in /<my path>/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:120
```

After this error, the entire vendor/symfony/finder directory is empty.

QUESTION: What's the best way to "refresh" my composer install to get the correct files back? I have reasons for not wanting to use the available server backup if I can avoid it.

Comment: You can run `composer install`.

Comment: (Assuming you're using git) you can just `git checkout` all your local changes. E.g. `git checkout vendor/symfony/finder`.

Comment: Thanks to Jaypan. Worked perfectly!